# Changing ImageView Image depending on previous fragment - Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, android-viewpager, bundle

I have a CreateActivity.java containing a viewpager adapter that initiates two Fragments - Fragment1.java and Fragment2.java. In Fragment1.java I have a listFragment setup, when the user clicks an item on that list, I want to switch the view to Fragment2.java and change the contents inside Fragment2.java (an image). What I've done so far:

In Fragment1.java set onClickListener for listview:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
    ((CreateActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Then passed to the main activity (CreateActivity) using interface. Then sent the position clicked data to Fragment2.java as a bundle:

```
public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Fragment2.ARG_POSITION, position);
    Fragment2 fragobj = new Fragment2();
    fragobj.setArguments(args);
    Log.w("listposition", "" + position);
}
```

Then recalled this value into Fragment2.java by override the setArguments method:

```
    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    int pos = args.getInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    Log.w("myApp", "" + pos);
}
```

How would I now go about setting the image I want according to the integer position? I have tried editing the image view like so, but get an NPE error (attached). Any ideas?

```
@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    int pos = args.getInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    Log.w("myApp", "" + pos);
    iv_ttx = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
    if (pos == 0){
        iv_ttx.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    } else if (pos == 1){
        iv_ttx.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832): java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at com.meme.hdmeme.Fragment2.setArguments(Fragment2.java:209)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at com.meme.hdmeme.CreateActivity.onArticleSelected(CreateActivity.java:44)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at com.meme.hdmeme.Fragment1.onListItemClick(Fragment1.java:65)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1102)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2751)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3425)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    09-03 00:32:57.053: E/AndroidRuntime(28832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

P.s. line 209 is:

```
    iv_ttx = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment2 fragobj = new Fragment2();
fragobj.setArguments(args);
```

The problem with above is that in `setArguments()` you're attempting to touch the fragment's view before the framework has had a chance to create it. Basically `getView()` returns `null`, hence the NPE.

In stead, move the relevant code over to any of the life cycle methods in which the view exists, i.e. `onCreateView()` `or onActivityCreated()`. You can get the set arguments by calling `getArguments()`:

```
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    int pos = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    Log.w("myApp", "" + pos);
    iv_ttx = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
    iv_ttx.setImageResource(pos == 0 ? R.drawable.img1 : R.drawable.img2);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, the problem I have is that when placed in onCreateView() or onActivityCreated() I get NPE. This is because I am attempting to return an integer that doesn't exist when the fragment is created. The integer is only created when the user clicks on an item in listview.

Comment: Why would you create the fragment without that integer value? I realise you've written it's in a `ViewPager`, but what's the purpose of that? If you want to show fragment B based on a choice in fragment A, then a `ViewPager` is not an obvious choice. That being said, forget about 'arguments', because you can't change those on-the-fly. A simple setter should do. Alternatively, Fragment B could be a container for child fragments, which you can replace based on the user's choice.

Comment: I have a ViewPager displaying three swipe tabs, when user clicks on the listview on the first tab (Fragment1) I would like it to switch to the second tab (Fragment2) and display relevant image. However I want the user to also have the option be able to swipe to the second tab (Fragment2) before selecting something from the listview contained in the First tab (Fragment1).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't showing in the error message, but by looking at the code, I'd say that a null pointer exception would also be coming from:

```
iv_ttx = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
```

You're attempting to get the view before onCreateView() has been called by the fragment manager.

Rather than overriding the setArguments() method, you could do it in the onCreateView method instead. So:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_id, container, false);
    ImageView iv_ttx = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_ttx);
    int pos = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    if (pos == 0) {
        iv_ttx.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    } else if (pos == 1){
        iv_ttx.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Hope that helps. I may have not 100% understood the question.

Comment: That's the thing, because the integer isn't created until the user clicks an item in the listview in Fragment1, this method will also return a NPE. This is why I chose to override the setArguemnts() method. Also, I thought that setArguments() method is called AFTER onCreateView has been called?